# Link docker container to a specific network interface

Tags: networking, docker, openvpn, docker-networking

I am trying to start OpenVPN server for accessing resources on VPC network.

I have two network interfaces, public eth0 and VPC eth1. And an OpenVPN working in a docker container. But I want to use this VPN only to access resources over eth1 interface. And make it impossible to access internet over that VPN.
So I want to map OpenVPN inbound port 1194/udp to eth0 in order to access VPN server. And have all outbound requests from inside that container to go over to eth1 interface.

Is it possible to do it with docker networks?